# Flask: How do you redirect to the same page with the same address, but with different content?

Tags: python, html, flask

I have created a website with simple login using database. I want it so that when you visit the homepage, it prompts you to sign up/login; and when you log in, it redirects to the same homepage but the homepage must not show the prompt (hinting that you're already logged in) and show content that is only available to logged in users instead. So its route must still be "/". I've tried this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url={{ url_for('index', authenticated=1) }}">
```

and in my Python file:

```
build = Flask(__name__)
@build.route('/')
def index(authenticated=0):
    if authenticated == 0:
        return render_template("index.html")
    elif authenticated == 1:
        return render_template("main.html")
```

Why did I want it to be that way? Well.. I don't want new users to visit that exclusive link. So unless there's a workaround where the exclusive link detects if the new user is not logged in, I don't know any other way to accomplish this

Comment: You usually store authentication-info in cookies. Maybe have a look at `Flask-Login`: https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: yeah but I already went with SQLAlchemy. well I'll use that as a last resort, thanks

Comment: Flask-Login works together with SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. To others who are reading this, here's my solution:
First you need to import `flask_login` and you must have it installed, you can do that by `pip install flask_login`.
Then, in your python file you need to import these:

```
from flask_login import UserMixin, login_user, LoginManager, login_required, logout_user, current_user
```

After that, create your `app` and configurate your `flask_login`:

```
app= Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app) # this is my database file, if you've already created it than you can leave it out
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login' # REPLACE login WITH YOUR LOGIN ROUTE, BUT DO NOT INCLUDE A SLASH (/) AND MUST BE IN QUOTES
login_manager.login_message = "You must be logged-in in order to view this page." # OPTIONAL: A CUSTOM FLASH MESSAGE THAT WILL BE SHOWN WHEN A SIGNED-OUT USER TRIES TO ACCESS PAGES THAT REQUIRE A LOGIN. YOU CAN DELETE IT IF YOU WANT THE DEFAULT MESSAGE

@login_manager.user_loader
def user(id):
    return Clients.query.get(int(id)) # REPLACE Clients WITH YOUR USER CLASS THAT IS USED TO AUTHENTICATE (NORMALLY IT INHERITS A DATABASE MODEL AND USERMIXIN)
```

Finally, scroll to a function that you want to restrict and apply a `@login_required` decorator (that is imported from flask_login) and it must be after `@app.route()`

```
@app.route('/exclusive_page_for_logged_in_users')
@login_required
def exclusive_page():
    return render_template('exclusive_page.html')
```

And to answer my original question:

```
@build.route('/')
def index():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return render_template("index.html")
    else:
        return render_template("authenticate.html")
```

You can see the condition `current_user.is_authenticated`. Don't replace anything, because that's how it's meant to be. That condition checks if the user is logged in or not, and if you're not logged in it loads `authenticate.html` instead of `index.html` while keeping the same route; hence you don't see a `@login_required` decorator.

Now, how do you log in then? You can use `login_user(YOUR_USER_INFO_FROM_DB)`
It's pretty simple, but you need a database to do that. You can search for the information in your database to validate them, which I won't include here.

```
pw_check_validation = Clients.query.filter_by(auth_name=auth_name).first()

login_user(pw_check_validation)

flash(f"Login successful.")
return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

and to log out, a simple `logout_user()` should do the trick.

```
# My code for log out    
@build.route("/end_session/?db_ID=<int:id>")
@login_required
def logout(id):
    logout_user()
    flash("You have been logged out.")
    return redirect(url_for('authenticate'))
```

Hope this helps anyone who has the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating two different routes also.

Just for example, here the `admin` route is for logged in users and `home` is for normal users. If the user is authenticated it redirects to the `admin` func.

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect(url_for('admin'))
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('home'))

@app.route("/admin")
def admin():
    return render_template('admin_home.html')

@app.route("/home")
def home():

    return render_template('home.html')
```

Comment: well yeah that definitely works. But how can I like mush them together into a single route and have them working

Comment: Here you can directly redirect the HTML page also , but above method will be recommended as like this you can add more logic and conditions if required.

Comment: huh. but can the new/unregistered user enter the exclusive page for logged in users by editing the link to `/admin`? i don't think the login function can stop that

Comment: Ya, you are right here, so here you can also put conditions like if a user is authenticated then redirect to home page else redirect to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

You must use redirects like this:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    if authenticated == 0:   
        return redirect('/login')
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    if authenticated == 1:   
        return redirect('/')
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Comment: I appreciate your comment but that didn't really work. It redirected to the homepage with the route as `/?authenticated=1` and not the original `/`

Comment: its bad practice transfer authenticated=1 by query string. You can save authentication flag in to your application (database or global var) and check it. But better is to use JWT for authentication https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/